# Redirect domain if no file/directory specified in URL using htacess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

I have a subdomain **images.example.com**, which, as the name suggests, delivers images to all of the other subdomains on example.com.

At the moment, I have set up the virtual host to apply all custom error documents from the parent domain like so:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.example.com/errors/400/
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.example.com/errors/401/
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/errors/403/
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/errors/404/
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/errors/500/
ErrorDocument 405 http://www.example.com/errors/405/
// And so on...
```

However, what I would like to do is redirect the visitor if they do not specify any file or directory. In other words, if they go to images.example.com, they will be redirected to www.example.com.

Example:

> images.example.com will redirect to www.example.com

but

> images.example.com/directory/ will not redirect

***The reason why I only want to redirect the first page is simply because, if you do not specify a document/directory, it shows the default Apache Server Test page instead of showing an error page.***

So, in short, how can I redirect a domain **only** if no file/directory has been specified in the URL?

Or, how can I prevent the default Apache Server Test page from showing when no file/directory has been specified?

### Last Resort

If I am unable to achieve this using my .htaccess, then I will just add a php page to teh root directory or the images subdomain and then just redirect from there...

### Further Information

I have read elsewhere that by specifying a **403** error document, then the Apache Server Test page will not be shown. Well this has not worked as I have specified the error and I am still seeing the test page...

Comment: I can’t see that you have actually _tried_ anything in terms of redirecting under the specified conditions. And btw., using absolute URLs for ErrorDocuments is not advisable, since that leads to a _redirect_. And for status 401 it is even plain _wrong_, as explicitly stated in the apache docs.

Comment: @CBroe I couldn't agree more, however I cannot see another way of taking the visitor to the correct error page as the error documents are outside the root directory of the subdomain. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could either duplicate the error documents in a location where they are accessible within the root of your subdomain, or use symlinks maybe …

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I will add the error documents to my subdomain and just include the content from the parent domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line by line we have:

1. turn rewrite engine on
2. is the request a file that doesnt exist
3. is the request a directory that doesnt exist
4. If so then redirect to www.example.com, this is the last rule.

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [L]

p.s. if images.example.com/directory/ will not redirect as it exists then images.example.com wont either.

I suggest creating an index.php and do:

```
header("Location:http://www.example.com");
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not bothered as to whether the directory/file actually exist as my error documents will handle this. Does this make a difference to your code?

Comment: not really. Since this is serving images, might I suggest you redirect to `/nofound.png` instead. At least this way you will always get an image. `<a href=""><img src="http://images.example.com/avatar.gif" /></a>` will still look okay